# Call another.js view from alloy.js titanium

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

have 1st view = index.js
2nd view = another.js

global file alloy.js

I have called the global class (alloy.js) method from index.js and now i want to move to another.js view  but after httpRequest method finishes (which is declared and implemented in alloy.js).

```
---alloy.js---

Alloy.Global.httpMethod=function(){

//xml response is achieved, now from here i want to navigate to another.js view

}

---index.js---

Alloy.Global.httpMethod();

---another.js---

//some UI objects.
```

Comment: isn't it just Alloy.createController('controllername').getView().open(); ?

Comment: thanks, i tried to that and didn't not achieved what I wanted. But after your comment i have checked my another.js file and it contains some errors supporting android and that was the reason it was not navigating to another.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is create a controller, your `another.js` must be a Controller, it can be created by doing Right click on app and creating a new controller from there.

Once your controller is created, you can easily do what Phil said in the comment. i.e

`Alloy.createController('another').getView().open();`

This has to be placed in your onload function of [HttpClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient).

Hope it Helps.